# Django models: Dependent fields

Tags: python, django, model

Say I have the following model:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    due_back = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    AVAILABILITY = (
        ('a', 'Available'),
        ('o', 'On loan'),
        ('n', 'Not available'),
        ('r', 'Reserved'),
    )

    status = models.CharField(choices=AVAILABILITY, blank=True)
```

My problem here is that the two fields `due_back` and `status` depend on each other. For example if the book is "on loan" it does not make sense to have a due_back date.

The goal is that the book  may only have a due_back date if the book is "on loan". But how to do this, are there "best practices" for this kind of problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am trying to reply to my own question. I further looked through the Django docs and it looks like that the `Model.clean()` method is a solution here.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean

In case somebody knows a better solution, please post. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this be using Django Validators.

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class Book(models.Model):

     ...
     def clean(self):
         if self.status == 'o' and self.due_back is not None:
            raise ValidationError('Error Book on Loan have due back date How !!!')
```